# The definition of Time and second

Tags: time, conventions, dimensional-analysis, si-units, metrology

From the book "University of Physics 15th edition", in chapter 1, they talk about the fundamental units. They stated that the definition of unit of time is based on an atomic clock, where 1**s** is defined as the time required for 9,192,631,770 **waves** by bombardment of microwaves on 133-cesium atom for electron transitions.

And then, they continued that length 1 **m** is defined as the distance that light travels in vacuum in 1/299,792,458 **s**.

My failing to understand is, why do we not define the time 1**s** from the speed of light $c$ instead of the atomic clock which is to me much more complex than the mechanical pendulum ones?

Comment: Re, "...more complex than the mechanical pendulum ones?" FYI: The pendulum clocks that were used as time standards until the mid 20th century actually were kind of complicated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortt%E2%80%93Synchronome_clock

Comment: @Solomon Slow You are right, I meant this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_watch. The one I own :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of SI is to define base units in terms of physical quantities that are very repeatably the same, and easy to measure with extreme precision. One of the most precise types of measurements in modern science is frequency.  Since frequency is measured as XXX per second, it is a perfect way of defining the second. No other measurement like length is needed.

The speed of light is measured in $m/s$, so it requires one of either length or time to already be defined. Since from the previous we have a second (and Hertz) defined, lengths can be measured with extreme precision using light interferometry.

Comment: So you are saying, that the higher frequency, the more accurate the second is? So if we use the orbital Earth on its own axis, in 24h, by 1/86400 Hz is not enough?

Comment: It's not necessarily important that it is high frequency.  It's important that it is extremely reliable and never changes, $and$ can be reproduced anywhere in a lab with the proper equipment. The Cesium frequency used to define the second has a value based on the energy levels inherent in a Cs atom.  In contrast, the Earth's rotation varies significantly, due to tectonic events, tidal forces from the Moon and Sun, and many other reasons.  That is why we have to make Leap Second adjustments every few years.

Comment: You just made me understand to realize how the precision is important to have a 1 second unaltered, to be in forever, like 500 million years for the Cs atom.